# Azure Stream Analytics query of nested array/record

Tags: azure, nested, powerbi, record, azure-stream-analytics

I have the following example of JSON which I am trying to send to PowerBI through Azure Stream Analytics.

```
[{

      "timestamp":1526452793090,
      "values":[
         {
            "id":"Device1.K1001",
            "v":false,
            "q":true,
            "t":1359326344047
         }
      ]
}]
```

My first assumption was to do the following query:

```
SELECT 
    timestamp,
    [values].id,
    [values].v,
    [values].q,
    [values].t
INTO
    [PowerBI]
FROM
    [IoTHub]
```

[result in powerBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BC4dl.png)

Why is the above solution wrong?

Best regards Michael

Comment: It is wrong because values is an array, and you are accessing it like it is a complex type.

Comment: @Michael You're welcome ,please mark this answer for others' reference,thx

Comment: @Michael You're welcome ,please mark this answer for others' reference,thx

Answer (score 3):

You could get [GetArrayElement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/streamanalytics/2016/02/23/handling-json-array-in-stream-analytics-query/) ,please refer to my sample query:

```
WITH 
temp AS
(
SELECT
timestamp ,
GetArrayElement([values],0)as valueObj 
FROM jsoninput 
)

SELECT
    temp.timestamp ,temp.valueObj.id,temp.valueObj.v,temp.valueObj.q,temp.valueObj.t
INTO
    jaycosmostest
FROM
    temp
```

***Output Result:***

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much. That is the solution. I failed to understand the array. Best regards Michael.

Comment: @Michael You're welcome ,please mark this answer for others' reference,thx

Comment: @Michael You're welcome ,please mark this answer for others' reference,thx